# How to start jupyter notebook with 'qt' backend by default

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'd like to not have to type `%matplotlib qt` every time I start a Jupyter notebook. I've read up on customizing matplotlib but I think this might be a Jupyter issue. The Jupyter configuration https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_overview.html has not helped me figure out how to set this default.

Not sure if this matters but I am using emacs-jupyter in Org Mode, not the traditional browser interface to Jupyter.